# can't pass json array

Tags: javascript, php, json, onload

I have an 'onload' handler for my web page, and it calls a javascript function  'handleLoad()' that has now stopped working (not being called) after I try to pass the output of json_encode in my PHP.

```
 <body onload="handleLoad('<?php echo $myJsonArr ?>')">
```

I have also tried:

```
 <body onload="handleLoad(<?php echo $myJsonArr ?>)">
```

and:

```
 <body onload='handleLoad("<?php echo $myJsonArr ?>")'>
```

playing around with the quotes, and nothing.  **handleLoad()** is not being called anymore.

This passing of **myJsonArr** now prevents the handleLoad() function from executing -- I know this because the 1st line of code in handleLoad(), which is javascript by the way, looks like this:

```
 function handleLoad(jsonArr)
 {
      alert("just entered handleLoad()");

      .....other code not shown, and 100% commented out during fixing this bug
 }
```

That 'alert' box above will appear fine -- until I added the 'jsonArr' JSON nested array, after which the 'alert' box is not showing up at all.   I removed all code from handleLoad() except the alert() box to eliminate any other cause -- and handleLoad() is not being invoked, despite the only thing now in handleLoad() is a simple call to alert().

The jsonArr is created like this, from a database read:

```
 $result = mysql_query($query);
 $numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);
 $theOuterArray = array();

 for($i = 0; $i < $numrows;  $i++)
 { 
    $theRow = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    $cityName = $theRow[1];
    $lat = $theRow[2];
    $lng = $theRow[3];
     // AND SO ON FOR address, titleOnly, recordNum, cityName, etc. used next....

    $nestedArray =  array($cityName, $lat, $lng, $i, $address, $titleOnly, 
                             $recordNum, $cityName, $stateName, $price);
    $theOuterArray[] = $nestedArray;
 }
 $myJsonArr = json_encode($theOuterArray);
 var_dump($myJsonArr);
```

Here's what the var_dump show me -- to keep things easy I only put one record in the database:

```
 string(136) "[["Auburn","32.6121","-85.4819",0,"Main Street","Test to debug why handleLoad() not being invoked","53378577","Auburn","Alabama","995"]]"
```

Is there something I'm missing here?   I successfully read the database, but creating then passing that json array to my "onload" handler is breaking the code.

EDIT:  suggested was to provide the source on my page in Firefox of the generated onload in the body tag, here it is:

```
  <body onload="handleLoad('[["Auburn","32.6121","-85.4819",0,"Main Street","Test to debug why handleLoad() not being invoked","53378577","Auburn","Alabama","995"]]')">
```

Comment: Could you post here the source code (just <body ...> line) after processed by PHP (in your browser)?

Comment: please check generated html - possible that your string broke code by adding " - so sttribute onload became invalid

Comment: @VasilVanchuk  I added the page source in the body tag's onload to my original post above.  QUESTION, if the simple data from fetch_row which I use to create an array is not processed correctly by json_encode -- how should I create the array to make json_encode give me a proper, "pass-able" json nested array?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using JQuery to get the json value via an Ajax call?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: previous jQuery answer removed.

This works.   You need to use htmlentities() on your json array before you pass it back.

php:

```
<?php

$myVar = '[["Auburn","32.6121","-85.4819",0,"Main Street","Test to debug why handleLoad() not being invoked","53378577","Auburn","Alabama","995"]]'; 

$myVar = htmlentities($myVar);

?>
```

HTML:

```
<body onload="handleLoad('<?php echo $myVar; ?>')">

   <script>
      function handleLoad(data) {
         alert(data);
      }
   </script>

</body>
```

Comment: Got it working.   There's something in your JSON array that's being flagged as html.   Using htmlentities() allowed me to use your json array in the onload attribute.

Comment: that works but why.  I have used htmlentities before, but never needed it for a body onload javascript function, I wonder why the browser is requiring it!

Comment: There must be something invisible in that JSON that htmlentities takes care of.   I echoed the string both before and after using htmlentities and the strings look identical in the browser.   It'll take a smarter man more versed in theory than me to say exactly what it was.  Please be sure to check this answer as solved (up by the upvote/downvote arrows) since it was of use to you.

Comment: As it turns out the htmlentities handles the quotes to make the nested array 'pass-able' but it cannot be refactored into a nested array in my handleLoad() -- my onload handler now successfully executes, but I'm sorry to say that I suspect now that json_encode is not a robust bundler of nested **vector** arrays (ie. non-associative arrays) -- I'll 'gin up' a name-value pair process when I create the nested arrays in php, I think json_encode can only handle "associative arrays" like ["itemOne":"item1", "itemTwo":"item2", ....] -- I'll impose name->value when I create my nested array to test.